# Error of Wrong Format in hive while loading data from hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hive, flume

I have successfully created a table but when m loading the data stored in hdfs streamed from twitter i got the error:

```
"Loading data to table default.tweets
Failed with exception Wrong file format. Please check the file's format.
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask"
```

I dont know what to do next . Here is the creation:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tweets (
    >    id BIGINT,
    >    created_at STRING,
    >    source STRING,
    >    favorited BOOLEAN,
    >    retweet_count INT,
    >    retweeted_status STRUCT<
    >       text:STRING,
    >       user:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
    >    entities STRUCT<
    >       urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>,
    >       user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
    >       hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
    >    text STRING,
    >    user STRUCT<
    >       screen_name:STRING,
    >       name:STRING,
    >       friends_count:INT,
    >       followers_count:INT,
    >       statuses_count:INT,
    >       verified:BOOLEAN,
    >       utc_offset:INT,
    >       time_zone:STRING>,
    >    in_reply_to_screen_name STRING
    > ) 
    > ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
    > LOCATION '/user/flume/tweets';
```

Please guide me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check in your Hive log files, you can get some additional information of the exception. Or please paste the exception part of log file.